# Hibernate batch updates with constraintviolationexception

Tags: hibernate, constraints

I'm updating a very large number of objects in batches and want to ignore any duplicates.
What is the best way of doing this?

My understanding is that if a `ConstrainViolationException` is thrown all the other objects in the batch will **NOT** be persisted.

Comment: Are you hoping that it's going to be transactional as well?  If so, you've got some difficulties in store...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
    private void saveBatch() {
    StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {
        for (Object t : batchList) {
            session.insert(t);
        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {

        log.info("Duplicate in batch...save individually");
        tx.rollback();
        session.close();
        saveIndividually();
        return;
    }

    session.close();
    batchList.clear();
}

private void saveIndividually() {
    StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
    for (Object t : batchList) {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.insert(t);
        try {
            tx.commit();
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            tx.rollback();
            log.warn("Ignoring duplicate: " + t);
        }

    }

    session.close();
    batchList.clear();
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a session.flush() in the topmost for-loop, as shows here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html. This will prevent running out of memory, and will let you detect constraintviolation sooner.

Comment: Dont think that will help. Commit automatically does a flush.

Comment: Right, but if your batchList is very large, you may run out of memory, so flushing periodically within the loop prevents this. See the link from my first comment for a more verbose explanation.

Comment: @DD. It is a nice code but the issue is in case of any duplicate we have to insert all data one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to insure consistency is to make sure all your entities' associations have the proper cascade options configured (like, if you want that a certain entity, when persisted, will also persist any new associated entities contained within its associations, you should configure cascade="save-update").

If you don't/ can't do that, the theoretical alternative is to create a separate transaction for each of your batch's operations (like each entity insertion), and if that transaction rolls back due to exception, you catch the exception and continue (possibly keeping a cache of the failed transactions to retry them later). This however will most likely not be practical, as it will take a whole lot longer to process than if you do all your operations inside one transaction (a true batch update).

Personally, when I'm confronted with such a scenario I do the batch operations via JDBC (using the Hibernate schema, and making sure to have the same sequences generation). This way it's faster and you can't more accuratelly deal with such issues.

Comment: Not sure what cascade has got to do with this...my entity doesnt have any associations.

Comment: If entity1 has a dependency towards entity2 without any cascade options, saving a new instance of entity1 which contains a new instance of entity2 will get you a ConstraintViolation