# Hibernate Batch insert/update constraintviolationexception

Tags: hibernate, batch-processing

I'm writing a program to run a batch process over hundreds of thousands of entities of a few related types.  I was originally doing this with a single transaction per persist.  This seemed very slow, so I tried doing somewhat naive batch updates in the way described in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html, with longer transactions and occasional flush+clears.  I'm running into a ConstraintViolationException for some of my entity types, because I have unique field constraints.  However, I'm unsure of how to check for existing instances; I currently have a criteria to list collisions, but it seems to not return entities that I have saveOrUpdated within the same transaction.

A made-up example may help:
entities Family, Person, Name
Family has many Persons (One to Many)
Persons have many names, different Persons can have the same Name. (Many to Many)

My updates include persisting a Family along with its Persons and Names, but I'm not sure how to dedupe Names (may collide with existing Name in db or another Name in the same update batch).  I could just keep track of new entities' unique constraint fields outside of hibernate, but I thought this is probably not necessary.  Is there any built-in way of checking for duplicates both in the db and uncommitted changes?  I saw [Hibernate batch updates with constraintviolationexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138559/hibernate-batch-updates-with-constraintviolationexception), but I do not savor using exceptions in the normal codepath.  Thanks, I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no. For batch operations, Hibernate doesn't keeps track of the generated ids, so, you'd have to go to the database for each `Name`, as you'd do a query based on the name, not on the ID, unless you are using some query cache (which would be tricky for your case, I suppose).

What I would suggest is to do this in a two-step (three?) process: first, batch-insert all `Name` objects. Then, load them all using Hibernate itself, storing them on a `Map`. Then, just persist the other data, linking the `Name` to the non-persisted `Person`. Of course, you'd need as much memory as you have names :-)  But why are you keeping `Name` as a separate entity, anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah, I guess one way or another I'll need to have a map outside of hibernate keyed on a tuple of the unique constraints per entity, at least per batch.  I just meant Name to be an illustration, in my actual application/schema/entities the many-to-many relation is more meaningful.